# Grouping CSV data in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am working on highcharts and testing its capabilities for analyzing large datasets. The thing is as far as i could figure, high charts does not group the data by categories unlike d3. I am using csv data file with highcharts for this.

E.g i can plot this data set:

```
Categories,Apples,Pears,Oranges,Bananas
John,8,4,6,5
Jane,3,4,2,3
Janet,3,16,13,15
Joe,8,8,8,8
```

and the resultant chart looks like:
[image]

Now when i add another row of data to the dataset e.g.

```
    Joe,4,4,4,4
```

this creates a chart with another bar segment for the categories. I need it to get grouped as happens in standard BI tools/excel, so that i just have one bar each category for Joe.

Is there some neat way of doing this using highcharts API?

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
    <!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

            <!-- 3. Add the container -->
    <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    <script src='testgraphs.js' type='text/javascript'></script>    
</body>
```

**JS Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Category Attrition1'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Units'
                }
            },
            series: []
        };


        $.get('newdata.csv', function(data) {
            // Split the lines
            var lines = data.split('\n');
            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                var items = line.split(',');

                // header line containes categories
                if (lineNo == 0) {
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                    });
                }

                // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
                else {
                    var series = { 
                        data: []
                    };
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo == 0) {
                            series.name = item;
                        } else {
                            series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                        }
                    });

                    options.series.push(series);

                }

            });

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });


    });
```

**Thank you in anticipation.**

Comment: How is it grouped in d3/excel?

Comment: *"Is there some neat way of doing this using highcharts API?"* No. You will need to pre-process your data outside of the chart, and pass it in grouped the way that you want it.